# Trying to scp files from an old Cisco C3560G to my PC : no matching key exchange method found

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to download files from an old Cisco C3560G to my PC but I get this error :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> ./scp.exe -pr admin@PAN-MGMT-01:c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\Desktop\Cisco\
Unable to negotiate with 10.14.16.15 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

So I do this :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> ./scp.exe -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -pr admin@PAN-MGMT-01:c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\Desktop\Cisco\
Unable to negotiate with 10.14.16.15 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

Then I tried this :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> ./scp.exe -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=+aes256-cbc -pr admin@PAN-MGMT-01:c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\Desktop\Cisco\
Password:
Administratively disabled.
```

EDIT0 : My Cisco C3560G was missing `ip scp server enable` but then I get :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> ./scp.exe -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=+aes256-cbc -pr admin@PAN-MGMT-01:c3560-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\Desktop\Cisco\
Password:
-p -r -d options not supported
```

EDIT1 : Removing the unsupported options `-pr` fixed the problem :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> ./scp.exe -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=+aes256-cbc admin@PAN-MGMT-01:PAN-MGMT-01_autoconfig-20230818.txt P:\Desktop\Switches\WS-C3560G-48PS-S\
Password:
PAN-MGMT-01_autoconfig-20230818.txt                                                                                                     100%   11KB  32.8KB/s   00:00
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH>
```

Comment: Looks like you already solved the "no matching key exchange method" problem yourself? Your third example shows SSH successfully making the handshake.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I finally found a solution, see my EDIT1.

Comment: @SebMa, add your solution as answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer